# Switch statement returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript

I have a switch statement that is running a formula but it is giving me a result of $0. If I run the same formula in an if statement I get the desired $46. Why isn’t the switch statement giving me the value of $46 but the IF statement is?

Switch Statement

```
        switch (true) {
        case ((VS_MTKL.match(/F../)) || (VS_MTKS.match(/M../))):
            VO_HOOK_0 = SoS_HFXD;
        break;
        default:
            var VO_HOOK_0 = 0;
        break;
    }
```

IF Statement

```
        if ((VS_MTKL.match(/F../)) || (VS_MTKS.match(/M../))) {
        VO_HOOK_0 = SoS_HFXD;
    } else {
        var VO_HOOK_0 = 0;
    }
```

Comment: The `var` declaration really should be outside the conditional in either case. It *works* as it is but it's strange. Also, the `if` is more readable anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `case` expression values in a `switch` are evaluated and then compared as if `===` were used in an `if`. The `.match()` function returns either null or an array, so it will never be `true`. It may be *truthy*, as an array is in an `if`, but that's a different situation.